# Crop image using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, image

This code is use to save a cropped image in the same place.

1. In this code  crop image from specific point the datax is x point of canvas
2. top position where crop start and
3. datay is y point of canvas top position and
4. datawidth is width of canvas
5. dataheight is height of canvas
6. img_scr path of file
7. canvas use for crop image

Below is the code described above:

```
  $targ_w = 396; // set the width of the new image
  $targ_h =400; //set the height og the new image

  $src = $_POST['img_src']; //get the image source
  $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src); //open the image
  $dst_r = imagecreatetruecolor( $targ_w,$targ_h); //create a new image

 imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['datax'],$_POST['datay'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['datawidth'],$_POST['dataheight']); // create the new image with the specified width and height from jcrop

  unlink($src); //delete the old image
  imagejpeg($dst_r,$src,100); // save the new image
  imagedestroy($img_r);
```

[Before crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjVj8.jpg)

[After Crop image is shrinking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhOgJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below script for cropping image.

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES["file"])) {
    $tmpFile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $fileName = 'file name';

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($tmpFile);
    // check if the file is really an image
    if ($width == null && $height == null) {
        header("Location: index.php");
        return;
    }
    // resize if necessary
    if ($width >= 400 && $height >= 400) {
        $image = new Imagick($tmpFile);
        $image->thumbnailImage(400, 400);
        $image->writeImage($fileName);
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file($tmpFile, $fileName);
    }
}
```

It would be helpful...

Comment: This code is for resize the image. We need to crop image.